# logistic regression- validation dataset

Tags: logistic, cross-validation

I am working on getting propensity of Households to buy a certain product, I have completed the training dataset for running proc logistic in SAS,
 my question is
1) My training dataset is a biased 50:50 ratio from the sample dataset of around 140k household i.e around 7500 Households

- While getting the validation dataset( unbiased ) the households set will be 140k right ? because my number of repondents was less I did not split the sample dataset into training and validation initially. so I need to pull the validation dataset completely now.

It would be nice if someone can help out or give suggestions on this ?

PS: working first time on Modeling